# Deriving default instances using GHC.Generics

Tags: haskell, generic-programming, deriving, scrap-your-boilerplate

I have a typeclass `Cyclic` for which I would like to be able to provide generic instances.

```
class Cyclic g where
    gen :: g
    rot :: g -> g
    ord :: g -> Int
```

Given a sum type of nullary constructors,

```
data T3 = A | B | C deriving (Generic, Show)
```

I want to generate an instance equivalent to this:

```
instance Cyclic T3 where
    gen   = A
    rot A = B
    rot B = C
    rot C = A
    ord _ = 3
```

I've tried to work out the required `Generic` machinery like so

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures, FlexibleContexts, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeOperators #-}

import GHC.Generics

class GCyclic f where
    ggen :: f a
    grot :: f a -> f a
    gord :: f a -> Int

instance GCyclic U1 where
    ggen   = U1
    grot _ = U1
    gord _ = 1

instance Cyclic c => GCyclic (K1 i c) where
    ggen = K1 gen
    grot (K1 a) = K1 (rot a)
    gord (K1 a) = ord a

instance GCyclic f => GCyclic (M1 i c f) where
    ggen = M1 ggen
    grot (M1 a) = M1 (grot a)
    gord (M1 a) = gord a    

instance (GCyclic f, GCyclic g) => GCyclic (f :*: g) where
    ggen = ggen :*: ggen
    grot (a :*: b) = grot a :*: grot b
    gord (a :*: b) = gord a `lcm` gord b

instance (GCyclic f, GCyclic g) => GCyclic (f :+: g) where
    ggen = L1 ggen
    -- grot is incorrect
    grot (L1 a) = L1 (grot a) 
    grot (R1 b) = R1 (grot b)
    gord _ = gord (undefined :: f a)
           + gord (undefined :: g b)
```

Now I can provide default implementations for `Cyclic` using `GCyclic`:

```
class Cyclic g where
    gen :: g
    rot :: g -> g
    ord :: g -> Int

    default gen :: (Generic g, GCyclic (Rep g)) => g
    gen = to ggen

    default rot :: (Generic g, GCyclic (Rep g)) => g -> g
    rot = to . grot . from

    default ord :: (Generic g, GCyclic (Rep g)) => g -> Int
    ord = gord . from
```

but my `GCyclic` instances are incorrect. Using `T3` from above

```
λ. map rot [A, B, C] -- == [B, C, A]
[A, B, C]
```

It's clear why `rot` is equivalent to `id` here. `grot` recurses down the `(:+:)` structure of `T3` until it hits the base case `grot U1 = U1`.

It was suggested on `#haskell` to make use of constructor information from `M1` so `grot` can choose the next constructor to recurse on, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Is it possible to generate the desired instances of `Cyclic` using `GHC.Generics` or some other form of Scrap Your Boilerplate?

**EDIT:** I *could* write `Cyclic` using `Bounded` and `Enum`

```
class Cyclic g where
    gen :: g
    rot :: g -> g
    ord :: g -> Int

    default gen :: Bounded g => g
    gen = minBound

    default rot :: (Bounded g, Enum g, Eq g) => g -> g
    rot g | g == maxBound = minBound
          | otherwise     = succ g

    default ord :: (Bounded g, Enum g) => g -> Int
    ord g = 1 + fromEnum (maxBound `asTypeOf` g)
```

but (as is) this is unsatisfying, as it requires all of `Bounded`, `Enum` and `Eq`. Additionally, `Enum` cannot be automatically derived by GHC in some cases whereas the more robust `Generic` can.

Comment: Maybe this doesn't fit your problem exactly, but you can provide sane defaults for those functions using just Enum and Bounded. Then all you have to do is declare the instance, no specific implementation needed. I'm on my phone right now, but I can provide an example later. I get the feeling that your actual use case is a bit more complicated though.

Comment: The only thing you need from `Bounded` and `Eq` is the ability to tell when you're at the last item to start iterating from some other `gen` again, which is what my answer adds. Note that adding `glast` to `GCylic` doesn't require that you add a corresponding function to `Cyclic` unless you intend to derive instances for `K1` (which you should totally do because it's awesome; the derived instance for `[T3]` might surprise you; it surprised me).

Comment: If you're going to start passing around `undefined` values as proxies for types, everything that implements `Cyclic` needs to accept `undefined` values, since some implementation might pass `undefined` to the other ones. You can avoid this by instead using `data Proxy a = Proxy` from the tagged package (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagged) and pass around `(Proxy :: ...)` instead. You'd change to `ord :: Proxy a -> Int`.

Comment: I don't want the `glast` abstaction to leak into `Cyclic`. I stubbed `gend` for `K1` with `const False`, and derived `instance Cyclic [T3]`. The result is pretty interesting, `iterate rot (gen :: [T3]) -> [[], [A], [B,A], [C,B,A], [A,C,B,A] ...]`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yeah, that's what surprised me for a moment.

Comment: You're already leaking a special point in the cycle due to `gen`. Imagine the function `rotIsGen :: (Eq a, Cyclic a) => a -> Bool` where `rotIsGen = (==gen) . rot`.

Comment: That's a good point, but I need a way to produce a value of type `forall a. Cyclic a => a` because I want to write functions polymorphic in `a`. If I don't export `Cyclic` (so no new instances can be written) and I choose the instances of `Cyclic` carefully I can be sure that the are no instances of `Eq`, so functions like `rotIsGen` can be avoided. `gen` also happens to fit into the abstraction as the generator of a cyclic group.

Comment: Recursing through `rotIsGen` for `K1` is wrong; it makes `gen` too special. Consider `iterate rot $ (Left (True, False) :: Either (Bool, Bool) T3)`. It only ever visits `Left (True, False)` and `Left (False, True)`, which has only 2 elements. On the other hand `Left (False, False)` generates `[Left (False, False), Left (True, True), Right A, Right B, Right C, Left (False, False), ...`

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. I've added an instance for `K1`, how would you implement `glast` for `K1`?

Comment: `glast` for `K1` isn't the problem, it's `rotIsEnd` for the `Cycle`, the problem is in the `GCycle` instance for products (`:*:`), since the product of two cyclic groups is a cyclic group iff their orders are coprime. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5969/product-of-two-cyclic-groups-is-cyclic-iff-their-orders-are-co-prime

Comment: In addition to my more than complete answer, which has gone way beyond deriving an instance for `T3`, there are a few other approaches you could take. You could move `ord` to the type level and require a type-level proof of the co-primeness of `Cyclic`s before deriving a product for them. You could only derive product instances for a type that provides a type-level proof that the values were arrived at by rotating the generator. You could change the interface of cyclic so that arbitrary values of the type can't be rotated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Edited after rereading what `ord` is supposed to mean, and again to try to address the [product of two cycles problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5969/product-of-two-cyclic-groups-is-cyclic-iff-their-orders-are-co-prime)*

You can figure out when to go to the other side of a sum of constructors if you can tell that whats inside is already at the last constructor, which is what the new `end` and `gend`  functions do. I can't imagine a cyclic group for which we can't define `end`.

You can implement `gord` for sums without even examining the values; the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension helps with this. I've changed the signatues to use proxies, since you're now mixing `undefined` and trying to deconstruct a value in your code.

```
import Data.Proxy
```

Here's the `Cyclic` class with `end`, defaults, and `Integral n` (instead of assuming `Int`) for `ord`

```
class Cyclic g where
    gen :: g
    rot :: g -> g
    end :: g -> Bool
    ord :: Integral n => Proxy g -> n

    default gen :: (Generic g, GCyclic (Rep g)) => g
    gen = to ggen

    default rot :: (Generic g, GCyclic (Rep g)) => g -> g
    rot = to . grot . from

    default end :: (Generic g, GCyclic (Rep g)) => g -> Bool
    end = gend . from

    default ord :: (Generic g, GCyclic (Rep g), Integral n) => Proxy g -> n
    ord = gord . fmap from
```

And the `GCyclic` class and its implementations:

```
class GCyclic f where
    ggen :: f a
    gend :: f a -> Bool
    grot :: f a -> f a
    gord :: Integral n => Proxy (f ()) -> n

instance GCyclic U1 where
    ggen   = U1
    grot _ = U1
    gend _ = True
    gord _ = 1

instance Cyclic c => GCyclic (K1 i c) where
    ggen        = K1 gen
    grot (K1 a) = K1 (rot a)
    gend (K1 a) = end a
    gord  _     = ord (Proxy :: Proxy c)

instance GCyclic f => GCyclic (M1 i c f) where
    ggen        = M1    ggen
    grot (M1 a) = M1   (grot a)
    gend (M1 a) = gend  a
    gord  _     = gord (Proxy :: Proxy (f ()))
```

I can't stress enough that the following is making an equivalence class over multiple cyclic subgroups of the product of the two cycles. Due to the need to detect ends for sums, and the face that the computations for `lcm` and `gcm` aren't lazy, we can no longer do fun stuff like derive a cyclic instance for `[a]`.

```
-- The product of two cyclic groups is a cyclic group iff their orders are coprime, so this shouldn't really work
instance (GCyclic f, GCyclic g) => GCyclic (f :*: g) where
    ggen           = ggen                          :*:  ggen
    grot (a :*: b) = grot  a                       :*:  grot  b
    gend (a :*: b) = gend  a                       &&   (any gend . take (gord (Proxy :: Proxy (f ())) `gcd` gord (Proxy :: Proxy (g ()))) . iterate grot) b
    gord  _        = gord (Proxy :: Proxy (f ())) `lcm` gord (Proxy :: Proxy (g ()))

instance (GCyclic f, GCyclic g) => GCyclic (f :+: g) where
    ggen        = L1 ggen
    grot (L1 a) = if gend a
                  then R1 (ggen)
                  else L1 (grot a)
    grot (R1 b) = if gend b
                  then L1 (ggen)
                  else R1 (grot b)
    gend (L1 _) = False
    gend (R1 b) = gend b
    gord  _     = gord (Proxy :: Proxy (f ())) + gord (Proxy :: Proxy (g ()))
```

Here are some more example instances:

```
-- Perfectly fine instances
instance Cyclic ()
instance Cyclic Bool
instance (Cyclic a, Cyclic b) => Cyclic (Either a b)

-- Not actually possible (the product of two arbitrary cycles is a cyclic group iff they are coprime)
instance (Cyclic a, Cyclic b) => Cyclic (a, b)

-- Doesn't have a finite order, doesn't seem to be a prime transfinite number.
-- instance (Cyclic a) => Cyclic [a]
```

And some example code to run:

```
typeOf :: a -> Proxy a
typeOf _ = Proxy

generate :: (Cyclic g) => Proxy g -> [g]
generate _ = go gen
    where
        go g = if end g
               then [g]
               else g : go (rot g)

main = do
    print . generate . typeOf $ A
    print . map rot . generate . typeOf $ A
    putStrLn []

    print . generate $ (Proxy :: Proxy (Either T3 Bool))
    print . map rot . generate $ (Proxy :: Proxy (Either T3 Bool))
    putStrLn []

    print . generate . typeOf $ (A, False)
    print . map rot . generate . typeOf $ (A, False)
    putStrLn []

    print . generate . typeOf $ (False, False)
    print . map rot . generate . typeOf $ (False, False)
    print . take 4 . iterate rot $ (False, True)
    putStrLn []

    print . generate $ (Proxy :: Proxy (Either () (Bool, Bool)))
    print . map rot . generate $ (Proxy :: Proxy (Either () (Bool, Bool)))
    print . take 8 . iterate rot $ (Right (False,True) :: Either () (Bool, Bool))
    putStrLn []
```

The fourth and fifth examples show off what's happening when we make an instance for the product of two cyclic groups whose orders are not coprime.

Comment: Oops, I misunderstood what you're looking for. Yout `gord` was already supposed to be my `gsize`.

Comment: What in particular are you not sure about in regards to products? The `Cyclic` instance for `(:*:)` is simple (if you know some basic algebra): `f :*: g` is equivalent to a direct product of cyclic groups `f`, `g`.

Comment: I figured it out when I put together `ord == size` and saw that you'd implemented it as `lcm`.